# Python open() function on server environment

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm running a flask app on my server and I'm reading a txt file from the same directory as the python file using the open() function. The function works when I run it locally but throws an error on the server.

This is my code:

```
def visitCounter():
   f = open('counter.txt', 'r+')
   real_visits = int(f.read())
   real_visits += 1
   f.seek(0)
   f.truncate()
   f.write('%d' % (real_visits))
   f.close()
   return real_visits


@app.route('/')
def index():
    real_visits = visitCounter()
    return render_template('index.html', real_visits = real_visits)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a similar problem and I believe it may be an issue with pathing, and the working directory may not be the directory in which the script is being called. Example of how to programmatically get relative path from the script location:

```
    import os
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #gets path of script
    rel_path = "counter.txt"
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
```